# how to make a xkcd style comic website

Tags: html, web-development

I am new to web development and I would like to know how to make an xkcd style comic website specifically the structure. xkcd.com has a separate folder for each comic with an `index.html` inside, but it seems like a lot of repetition to copy the almost exact same index file into every folder. Is there a more intelligent way to do this?

I don't want to use websites like Wordpress.

Comment: There are hundreds of platforms, programming languages, libraries, and techniques that could be used.   "How do I build a web site" is not a question that can be answered in a few paragraphs without introducing biased opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm, I don't think that's the way Randall (creator of xkcd) post his comics.

It seems that you believe that this is his way because you learned that the `2148` of that URL `https://xkcd.com/2148/` is a folder on the server, which has inside an `index.html` file.

While this *CAN* be one way to do that, there are plenty of ways, for example using some framework based on the coding language of your choice.

In simple words: normally there are a piece of software that runs on the server, which get your request (ie: `https://xkcd.com/2148/`), elaborate it gluing together the "main template" (header, footer, layout) and the comic requested (`2148`).

If you want to learn how to do it, I'll suggest you to look over some simple php framework, like **laravel**, with some tutorial.

It may be confusing at the beginning, but it's a good start if you want to use PHP.

Alternatively, in this answer are present some very good advice to start learning web development: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/15329/336186